# Cross-platform game to be wrapped into a native iOS/Android app

Tags: android, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cross-platform

I need to build an app like Lumosity (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lumoslabs.lumosity) that is native app and have some game screens.

So the question is: Is there a way to build a cross-platform game that I could wrap it into a native iOS/Android app?

I've read about Cocos2D-x that is great to build the hole game but I found nothing about wrapping like GLView as a subView.